# .htaccess 500 internal server error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authorization, .htpasswd

Hi trying to password protect my wordpress website by using .htaccess & .htpasswd, but i keep getting an error "500 Internal Server Error"

I think its because of the AuthUserFile part of the .htaccess file.

on my wordpress header i have entered the following php code to get the current directory

```
<?php echo getcwd(); ?>
```

and it returns as:

```
/var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain_com
```

this is my .htaccess file. maybe you guys can figure it out.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /var/sentora/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/domain_com/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

also, the .htaccess & the .htpasswd files are both in the `/domain_com` directory.

Comment: Remove `AuthGroupFile /dev/null` . Is your .htpasswd file created properly?

Comment: I removed AuthGroupFile and it then asked for username and password, but when i entered the username and password it just said internal server error again. And it wont ask again unless i clear cache. And Yes im pretty sure the .htpasswd file is setup correctly. It just looks like this:  testing:$apr1$3rgql2e5$KfVGiIpX3I2Z7DQ/39Q0Y0

Comment: Check your Apache error.log when 500 came.